# Testing AngularJS scope variables

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-switch

I'm trying to implement a test that relies on a scope variable. I want to enable **ng-switch-when** to resolve an expression. This is what I'm trying to do (**UPDATE** using $rootScope):

```
it('should switch on array changes', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  element = $compile(
    '<div ng-switch="select">' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="test[0]">test[0]:{{test[0]}}</div>' +
    '</div>')($rootScope);
  expect(element.html()).toEqual('<!-- ngSwitchWhen: test[0] -->');
  $rootScope.test = ["leog"];
  $rootScope.select = "leog";
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('test[0]:leog');
}));
```

My problem is that *the implementation I have for this to work does not get the scope variable "test" to evaluate* and work as I expect. Here is the implementation:

```
var ngSwitchWhenDirective = ngDirective({
  transclude: 'element',
  priority: 800,
  require: '^ngSwitch',
  compile: function(element, attrs) {
    return function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
      var expr = scope.$eval(attrs.ngSwitchWhen),
          ngSwitchWhen = expr !== undefined ? expr : attrs.ngSwitchWhen;
      ctrl.cases['!' + ngSwitchWhen] = (ctrl.cases['!' + ngSwitchWhen] || []);
      ctrl.cases['!' + ngSwitchWhen].push({ transclude: $transclude, element: element });
    };
  }
});
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify, this is an example of how ng-switch it's being tested from the Angular team. Just to show that I'm doing my test in a similar way but not having the expected result.

And also, I forgot to reverse my code to $rootScope, what you've been seeing up until now was one of my attempts to make this work creating a new scope to avoid relying on $rootScope for a change.

```
it('should switch on value change', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    element = $compile(
      '<div ng-switch="select">' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="1">first:{{name}}</div>' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="2">second:{{name}}</div>' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="true">true:{{name}}</div>' +
      '</div>')($rootScope);
    expect(element.html()).toEqual(
       '<!-- ngSwitchWhen: 1 --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: 2 --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: true -->');
    $rootScope.select = 1;
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('first:');
    $rootScope.name="shyam";
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('first:shyam');
    $rootScope.select = 2;
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('second:shyam');
    $rootScope.name = 'misko';
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('second:misko');
    $rootScope.select = true;
    $rootScope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).toEqual('true:misko');
}));
```

Comment: does it work outside of the test? what does element.text() return when the test runs?

Comment: Yes, it does work on a real use case. When the test runs the **element.text()** is '' (empty string). Debugging it I found that the scope variable on the compile inner function, does not have the "test" property as I do have on the real use case. Perhaps this has something to do with scope visibility.

Comment: This might reveal my ignorance, but can you confirm the aim of your test? It seems like you've posted the AngularJS source of ngSwitchWhen: are you trying to test that?

Comment: As I described, I want to have the ng-switch-when from Angular to resolve expressions, in the case of this test, have the ng-switch value match an array value.

Comment: Is it because you are compiling the HTML before test is defined in the scope? Therefore, test[0] is going to be undefined as well.

Comment: Does it work if you move `$scope.test=...` to the line above `element = $compile...`?

Comment: Actually @Jonathan, that is on purpose as the test firstly expects "<!-- ngSwitchWhen: test[0] -->" which asserts because there is no option to show due to an empty $scope. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My bad, after changing back to $rootScope and moving $rootScope.test before compiling I was able to resolve the issue, thanks a lot @Jonathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after moving some code around I found that the variables not involved on making $rootScope change to test the feature, should be defined before compiling the element to test. Thanks @Jonathan for the hint.

Here is the working code with additional test cases:

```
it('should evaluate expressions to match switch value', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $rootScope.array = ["leog", ".me"];
  $rootScope.obj = {"key": "value"};
  $rootScope.$apply();
  element = $compile(
    '<div ng-switch="select">' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="obj.key">obj.key:{{obj.key}}</div>' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="array[0]">array[0]:{{array[0]}}</div>' +
      '<div ng-switch-when="array[1]">array[1]:{{array[1]}}</div>' +
    '</div>')($rootScope);
  expect(element.html()).toEqual('<!-- ngSwitchWhen: obj.key -->' +
                                 '<!-- ngSwitchWhen: array[0] -->' +
                                 '<!-- ngSwitchWhen: array[1] -->');
  $rootScope.select = "value1";
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('obj.key:value');
  $rootScope.select = "leog";
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('array[0]:leog');
  $rootScope.select = ".me";
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(element.text()).toEqual('array[1]:.me');
}));
```

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.$apply needs to have a function inside of the parenthesis that is to be executed, which your test code is lacking. To get things to happen while testing I use $scope.$digest() (instead of $scope.$apply(); This kicks off a manual digest cycle that would not otherwise be running in the test.

Comment: Already tested your two possible solutions and nothing. Thanks anyway @MBielski